# Fetching HTML data to load pages faster - Opera Turbo

Tags: javascript, opera-turbo

I've discovered a pretty cool function on Opera which is fetching data on website, it shows lower resolution images and things like that and page loads fast. This is great for slow connections.

I'm interested in the background of this little function, with my basic knowledge of CSS, HTML and Javascript I don't understand how this can be done. Can anyone explain how does it work?

I mean let's say for images, it needs to download the image first and then convert it to lower resolution one so where do we "win" time here? Image is still being downloaded right?

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say it's non-trivial for you to achieve what you are trying to do. If you take a look at [Opera Turbo](http://www.opera.com/turbo)

### How we squeeze out all that speed

When Opera Turbo is enabled, webpages are compressed via Opera's servers so that they use much less data than the originals. This means that there is less to download, so you can see your webpages more quickly.

Enabling Opera Turbo is as simple as clicking the Opera Turbo icon at the bottom-left of the Opera browser window. When you are on a fast connection again and Opera Turbo is not needed, the Opera browser will automatically disable it.

---

Your best bet is to follow up on [How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701328/how-do-i-check-connection-type-wifi-lan-wwan-using-html5-javascript), depending on their connection type, load your images accordingly, **but** be aware that, a connection type cannot accurately let you determine their network speed. A device can be on 3G or LTE but still getting crappy speeds from their provider.

If you really want to implement this feature and be safe to work across browsers & devices, i can suggest putting lazyload plugins like [Unveil](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) that will help with the amount of data on load. **OR** include a button within your page that allow the user to select a *low bandwidth* option, something like what gmail does

[image: for slow connections]

Answer (score 1):

Turbo mode is really great feature of Opera.

In short, it downloads complete code and images to Opera servers and then send them to user. **Turbo mode is big traffic-saver** (up to 80%). Opera then decompresses data on-the-fly, while answering user's request. Well, images in Turbo mode are almost useless but still, this mode basically comes handy when you use extremely slow internet-speed.

You can check out official documentation to find more info. Also, check out my old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5684217/679733) where I wrote about Turbo mode. There you can find more info and useful links about this topic.

Additionally, look at info on `opera-turbo` tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opera-turbo/info), on StackOverflow.